# Formats Error (could not find ldd binary)!

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, yum, ldd

I'm using CentOS5 and trying to install a script that requires `ldd`.

I've tried:

```
yum install gcc glibc glibc-common 
yum update gcc glibc glibc-common
Yum reinstall yum gcc glibc glibc-common
```

The first two say it's already installed, the latter obviously just reinstalls without error.

So my problem is the script I'm using (AVS) still claims the `ldd` binary is missing.

Is there a default directory where it should be installed? I have the following files:

```
ld
ldd
lddlibc4
```

In both /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: ldd should be in /usr/bin/ldd; which is the error? what happens if you edit the script and provide a full path to ldd?

Answer (score 0):

ldd is not a binary, it is a Text file, with bash script inside. You should debug your script (AVS) or contact with its author.

Answer (score 0):

You may have removed ldd executable manually and yum/rpm can not detect that. You can download the "glibc-common" rpm package from some mirror and reinstall it by force.